# Matching strings when comparing two lists in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to match strings that are similar from two lists and the result to be `True` if there is a match. So far I am getting only `False` tried with comprehension and set interesection the result was the same.

What I have right now:

```
a = ['The weather today is awful', 'Last night I had a bad dream']

b = ['The weather today is awful and tomorow it will be probably the same', 'Last night I had a bad dream about aliens']

match = any([item in a for item in b])
print(match)
```

So what I am trying to do is to match `The weather today is awful` from list `a` with the sentence of list `b` and `Last night I had a bad dream` with the sentence of list `b` and so on...

Comment: Have a look at [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or other "string distance" metrics. There are some libraries for python available. Could you provide some other examples of "strings that are similar"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like:

```
match = any(ia in ib for ia in a for ib in b)
```

Or, using `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

match = any(ia in ib for ia, ib in product(a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're still comparing full strings (and backwards), by checking if any item in b, is in the list a, not the strings within a

```
any(item in x for x in b for item in a)
```

I presume you want to check if any string in a, is within a string in the list b

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match **each** item in a against *any* item in b, then you can do:

```
[any(item in item2 for item2 in b) for item in a]
```

If you want to match each item in a against only the item in b at the corresponding index, then you can do:

```
[item in item2 for item, item2 in zip(a,b)]
```

Both of these return `[True, True]` with the current example:

```
a = ['The weather today is awful', 'Last night I had a bad dream']

b = ['The weather today is awful and tomorow it will be probably the same', 'Last night I had a bad dream about aliens']
```

but if for example you reversed the ordering of `b`:

```
b = b[::-1]
```

then the first expression wouold still return `[True, True]`, whereas the second one would now return `[False, False]` -- in other words, the first element of `a` is now contained in *an* element of `b` but not the first one, and similarly the second element of `a` is now contained in *an* element of `b` but not the second one.

If you are just interested in whether **any** item in `a` is contained in any item in `b`, or the corresponding item in `b`, then use these list comprehensions (or better, the analogous generator expression) as input to `any`.  For example:

```
any(any(item in item2 for item2 in b) for item in a)
```

tests if *any* item in `a` is contained in *any* item in `b`

or

```
any(item in item2 for item, item2 in zip(a,b))
```

tests if *any* item in `a` is contained in the *corresponding* item in `b`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `any()` with `startswith()` to achieve the reult without importing anything:

```
a = ['The weather today is awful', 'Last night I had a bad dream']

b = ['The weather today is awful and tomorow it will be probably the same', 'Last night I had a bad dream about aliens']

print(any([item2.startswith(item1) for item1, item2 in zip(a, b)])) # True
```